# Quisiera saber cuál es mi error?

Tags: python

El programa lo que debería hacer es leer la lista que ingreso en *expo* y en el modulo `calculo_exponente(expo)` deberá:

1) Fijarse si se compone de 0, en cuyo caso se trasformará a *expo* = -126.

2) Fijarse si se compone de 1, en cuyo caso *expo* = 'Nan'.
o

3) Si no se da ninguno de los dos casos, deberá resolver normalmente.

'''

## Funciones

```
def es_cero(x):

    """define si el exponente es 0"""

    cont = 0
    for i in x:
        if (x[i] == 0):
            cont =+1
    if (cont == len(x)):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok

def es_255(exp):

    """define si el exponente es 255"""

    cont = 0
    for i in exp:
        if (exp[i] == 1):
            cont =+1
    if (cont == 8):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok

def calculo_exponente(exp):

    """define el numero que reprensenta el exponente"""

    print('el exponente al entrar a la funcion: ', exp)

    if (es_cero(exp)):
        exp = -126
    elif (es_255(exp)):
        exp = 'NaN'
    else:
        exponente = 0
        j = 7
        for i in range(0,8):
            if (exp[i] == 1):
                exponente = exponente + (1*(2**j))
            j = j-1
        exp = exponente - 127
        return exp

#Inicio del Programa

expo = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]

print(len(expo))

calculo_exponente(expo)

print('El exponente que sale es:', expo)
'''
```

Realmente no me sale ningún error de typeo, y creo que está bien hecho, sin embargo cuando la función retorna *expo*, me vuelve a retornar la lista, como si no hubiese procesado nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando iteras sobre un iterable cualquiera con un `for in`  en cada iteración a la variable del ciclo se asocia una referencia al elemento del iterable de turno, no el índice del mismo. En vez de:

```
for i in x:
    if (x[i] == 0):
```

debe ser:

```
for i in x:
    if i == 0:
```

Por otro lado **`cont =+1` asigna a `cont` el valor `+1` no suma `1` a `cont`, debe ser `+=` no `=+`**

```
def es_cero(x):

    """define si el exponente es 0"""

    cont = 0
    for i in x:
        if (i == 0):
            cont += 1
    if (cont == len(x)):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok
```

Aunque mejor usa directamente `list.count`:

```
def es_cero(x):
    """define si el exponente es 0"""
    if (x.count(0) == len(x)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

o mejor aún `all()`:

```
def es_cero(x):
    """define si el exponente es 0"""
    if all(n == 0 for n in x):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Lo mismo se aplica para la función `es_255`.

Por otro lado, tienes dos errores más:

- En `calculo_exponente(exp)` el `return` debe estar fuera del `else`, al mismo nivel de identación que éste.
- Te devuelve la lista como si no la procesara porque imprimes la lista como tal:

  ```
  print('El exponente que sale es:', expo)
  ```

  cuando debes imprimir la salida de la función `calculo_exponente`.

En definitiva, debería ser algo así:

```
def es_cero(exp):
    """define si el exponente es 0"""
    cont = 0
    for i in exp:
        if (i == 0):
            cont += 1
    if cont == len(exp):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok


def es_255(exp):
    """define si el exponente es 255"""
    cont = 0
    for i in exp:
        if i == 1:
            cont += 1
    if cont == len(exp):
        ok = True
    else:
        ok = False
    return ok


def calculo_exponente(exp):
    """define el numero que reprensenta el exponente"""

    print('el exponente al entrar a la funcion: ', exp)

    if (es_cero(exp)):
        exp = -126
    elif (es_255(exp)):
        exp = 'NaN'
    else:
        exponente = 0
        j = 7
        for i in range(0, 8):
            if (exp[i] == 1):
                exponente = exponente + (1*(2**j))
            j = j-1
        exp = exponente - 127
    return exp


# Inicio del Programa

expo = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
numero = calculo_exponente(expo)
print('El numero que sale es:', numero)
```

Comment: OMFG gracias serpiente del saber!